# integer conversion fails when a certain bit is set on

Tags: c#, arrays, blob

Most confused - we are trying to process an octet-stream binary file.  We have various possible destination structs.  The incoming file is a string of x bytes - a blob - which we understand we first need to convert to a byte array.  We use a FOR loop to move a byte at a time to the byte array.  Then, when we know the specific struct of the data - as defined by a fixed-position text field within the data - we use a deserialize routine specific to that struct.  Character arrays use one deserialize function to populate string variables, integer fields populate other variables (generally UINT16s), and so on through the received data. When we know we have an int16 (2-byte integer) processing fails if the low order integer's byte 8 is set to negative.  We don't know if the 8-bits in the FOR loop is integer, char, or what  until after the blob has been moved to the byte-array using the FOR loop (standard

```
for (i=1, I <= blob_length, i++) 
{dest(i) = source(i); }
```

)and we have identified which struct is in play.

By the time we exit deserialize, we see the data is corrupted as follows:

so  decimal 511 binary 01 11111111 converts to decimal 256 binary 01 00000000

but decimal 383 binary 01 01111111 converts correctly

We cannot tell if the FOR loop processing is somehow unable to handle an 8-bit field if the high-order bit is on, or if the actual deserialize process for the UINT16 is failing.  We have struggled through other ascii-related issues where that 8th bit corrupts processing.  Not sure this is yet another, or if it's something else.

Any insight or guidance would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code segment?

Comment: The tiny code segment you are showing does not even compile and does not show any conversion from byte[] to any other type. So it's really hard to to tell. Please show **real** code being really relevant and that compiles!

Comment: What are `dest` and `source` types? If they are arrays, you should use `[i]` instead of `(i)`. And your code doesn't seem to do much work, apart from copying `source` to `dest`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the indexes are 0-based and the for-loop should look like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < blob_length; i++) {
    dest[i] = source[i]; 
}
```

Probably you were one byte off.

Comment: you are right - I transferred the code wrong.  We did start at 0.  If we started at 1 all bytes would be wrong, in fact only the bytes with the high-order bit are wrong.

Comment: Your code does not show anything relevant for the conversion problems. It is just showing how you are copying something.

Comment: I understand your question.  I am not the code author - I work on the "other side of the fence" from the guys that are coding this, and are unable to determine why that particular bit pattern fails.   Once the web code receives the blob, it goes through the FOR loop copying from a string array to a byte array.  I don't understand why they can't MEMCOPY this, but it won't compile if they do.

Comment: It is simply not possible to tell what's going on without seeing the relevant code.

Comment: try
            {
                string Response;
                int Res_lenght;
                using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)await webRequest.GetResponseAsync())
                using (Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream())
                using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(streamResponse))
                {
                    Response = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
                    Res_lenght = Response.Length;
                }

Comment: {
                    recvbytes = ConvertToBytes(Response);  
                    var table = (Encoding.Default.GetString(
                           recvbytes,
                           0,
                           recvbytes.Length - 1)).Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" },
                                                            StringSplitOptions.None);
                }

Comment: this is the FOR loop used:        static byte[] ConvertToBytes(string inputString) 
        { 
            byte[] outputBytes = new byte[inputString.Length * sizeof(char)/2];
            for (int i=0;i<inputString.Length;i++)          {
                try
                {
                    outputBytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(inputString[i]);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }

            } 
            return outputBytes;

Comment: It must be `GetString( recvbytes, 0, recvbytes.Length)` without `- 1`, since the third parameter is the count. See: Encoding.GetString Method (Byte[], Int32, Int32)] https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05cts4c3(v=vs.110).aspx. Why `sizeof(char)/2`? But include this code in your question, please. It is difficult to read here.

Comment: Working on getting the whole code snippet to show up - may need to restart thread.  Not used to the rules on this forum - my apologies.  To answer the "/2" question, its because sizeof(char) returned 2, not 1, so we had a double of the actual size returned.

Comment: This makes no sense. If one byte per char is used in the stream, then use `String.Length` bytes. If the stream uses the same format as the C# in-memory format, use `String.Length * sizeof(char)` bytes. C# uses 16 bit per char. (You can simply click on the edit-link below your question in order to work on your question. Indent code snippets by 4 spaces and they will be formatted as code.)